# Can I move from &mut self to &self within the same function?

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker

I'm trying to learn a bit of Rust through a toy application, which involves a tree data structure that is filled dynamically by querying an external source. In the beginning, only the root node is present. The tree structure provides a method `get_children(id)` that returns a `[u32]` of the IDs of all the node's children — either this data is already known, or the external source is queried and all the nodes are inserted into the tree.

I'm running into the following problem with the borrow checker that I can't seem to figure out:

```rust
struct Node {
    id: u32,
    value: u64, // in my use case, this type is much larger and should not be copied
    children: Option<Vec<u32>>,
}

struct Tree {
    nodes: std::collections::HashMap<u32, Node>,
}

impl Tree {
    fn get_children(&mut self, id: u32) -> Option<&[u32]> {
        // This will perform external queries and add new nodes to the tree
        None
    }

    fn first_even_child(&mut self, id: u32) -> Option<u32> {
        let children = self.get_children(id)?;
        let result = children.iter().find(|&id| self.nodes.get(id).unwrap().value % 2 == 0)?;
        Some(*result)
    }
}
```

Which results in:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.nodes` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:19:43
   |
18 |         let children = self.get_children(id)?;
   |                        ---- mutable borrow occurs here
19 |         let result = children.iter().find(|&id| self.nodes.get(id).unwrap().value % 2 == 0)?;
   |                                      ---- ^^^^^ ---------- second borrow occurs due to use of `self.nodes` in closure
   |                                      |    |
   |                                      |    immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                      mutable borrow later used by call
```

Since `get_children` might insert nodes into the tree, we need a `&mut self` reference. However, the way I see it, after the value of `children` is known, `self` no longer needs to be borrowed mutably. Why does this not work, and how would I fix it?

##### EDIT -- my workaround

After Chayim Friedman's answer, I decided against returning `Self`. I mostly ran into the above problem when first calling `get_children` to get a list of IDs and then using `nodes.get()` to obtain the corresponding `Node`. Instead, I refactored to provide the following functions:

```
impl Tree {
    fn load_children(&mut self, id: u32) {
        // If not present yet, perform queries to add children to the tree
    }

    fn iter_children(&self, id: u32) -> Option<IterChildren> {
        // Provides an iterator over the children of node `id`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrading a mutable reference into a shared reference produces a reference that should be kept unique. This is necessary for e.g. [`Cell::from_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/cell/struct.Cell.html#method.from_mut), which has the following signature:

```rust
pub fn from_mut(t: &mut T) -> &Cell<T>
```

This method relies on the uniqueness guarantee of `&mut T` to ensure no references to `T` are kept directly, only via `Cell`. If downgrading the reference would mean the unqiueness could have been violated, this method would be unsound, because the value inside the `Cell` could have been changed by another shared references (via interior mutability).

For more about this see [Common Rust Lifetime Misconceptions: downgrading mut refs to shared refs is safe](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md#9-downgrading-mut-refs-to-shared-refs-is-safe).

To solve this you need to get both shared references from the same shared reference that was created from the mutable reference. You can, for example, also return `&Self` from `get_children()`:

```rust
fn get_children(&mut self, id: u32) -> Option<(&Self, &[u32])> {
    // This will perform external queries and add new nodes to the tree
    Some((self, &[]))
}

fn first_even_child(&mut self, id: u32) -> Option<u32> {
    let (this, children) = self.get_children(id)?;
    let result = children.iter().find(|&id| this.nodes.get(id).unwrap().value % 2 == 0)?;
    Some(*result)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Is returning `&Self` in this way a common pattern? It looks a bit awkward.

Comment: @Mark downgrading the reference is not a common pattern (and a bit of antipattern, even), so returning `&Self` by definition can't be common :) I don't know about other solutions, and this trick is somewhat orthogonal to what most people that downgrades a reference (e.g. `Cell::from_mut()`) do, i.e. return the whole object and not just parts of it.